# Plotly choroplethmapbox not rendering data / polygon geometries

Tags: geopandas, choropleth, plotly

I have a geoDataFrame with valid geometries and I use `__geo_interface__` to create feature collections object which is passed to `geojson` property.

Reference doc: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Choroplethmapbox.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BnITg4z7_u3bQolnLJ08huiEMP-aManK/view?usp=sharing' 

df = pd.read_csv('')

# Convert to GeoDataFrame
gdfc = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfc, geometry='tract_geom')

s = gdfc['Home_Value'].astype(float)

label = "Median Home Value"


   MAPBOX_KEY = "xxxxx"

   data = []

   datad.append({

                        "type": "choroplethmapbox",
                        "geojson": gdfc.__geo_interface__,
                        "locations": gdfc['tract_ce'],
                        "z": s,
                        "featureidkey": "properties.tract_ce",
                        "hovertext": gdfc['lsad_name'],
                        "autocolorscale":False,
                        "colorscale":"Portland",
                        "colorbar":dict(
                                        title = dict(text=label,
                                                     font=dict(size=12)
                                                    ),
                                        orientation = 'v',
                                        x= -0.15,
                                        xanchor= "left",
                                        y= 0,
                                        yanchor= "bottom",
                                        showticklabels=True,
                                        thickness= 20,
                                        tickformatstops=dict(dtickrange=[0,10]),
                                        titleside= 'top',
                                        ticks= 'outside',
                                        font = dict(size=12)
                                       ),
                        "zmin": s.min(),
                        "zmax": s.max(),
                        "marker_line_width": 0,
                        "opacity": 0.2,
                        "labels": label,
                        "title": "Choropleth Map"

                     }
        )

 
layout = {

             "autosize": True,
             "hovermode": "closest",
             "mapbox": {

                 "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                 "bearing": 0,
                 "center": {
                     "lat": layout_lat,
                     "lon": layout_lon
                 },
                 "pitch": 0,
                 "zoom": zoom,
                 "style": "outdoors",

             },

             "margin": {
                "r": 0,
                "t": 0,
                "l": 0,
                "b": 0,
                "pad": 0
            }

}
```

[image]